# Amazon Redshift Automated Snapshot Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, backup, snapshot

What actually triggers an automatic incremental backup/snapshot for Amazon Redshift? Is it time-based? The site says it "periodically takes snapshots and tracks incremental changes to the cluster since the last snapshot" and I know whenever I modify the cluster(either delete, modify size, or change node type) itself, a snapshot is taken. But what about when a database on the cluster is altered? I have inserted, loaded, deleted many rows but no automatic snapshot is taken. Would I just have to do manual backups then?

I have asked around and looked up online and no one has been able to give me an answer. I am trying to figure out an optimal backing strategy for my workload.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or maybe [Amazon Web Services](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60900/amazon-web-services) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Automated backups are taken every 8 hours or every 5 GB of inserted data, whichever happens first.

Source: I work for AWS Redshift.